# Select consecutive elements in Android GridView

Tags: java, android

I have a GridView that's filled up with calendar days for each month. Each day represents a toggle button with its background changing on button click. I would like to have it in such way that if I start   clicking the 14th of September, for example, make it possible to click only the following days: 15th, 16th, etc.. So only consecutive elements :) BUT not possible to select other random dates after the first clicked element, such as 31st, 28th..

Comment: As I'm assuming that the listener is set directly on those buttons you could simply call `setEnabled(false)` on all positions below the current position clicked by the user.

Comment: @Luksprog .. You're right, but for instance, I would like to select from 20th to 25th. setEnabled(false) for the previous elements would do half the trick, but I could still go for other random elements, such as 28th, 31st

Comment: It's not very clear how exactly do you plan to do the selection. If you want to allow only selecting of the right next item then do a loop and call setEnabled(false) for all items except the initial selected position and the next one in the GridView.

Comment: Sorry I don't use Skype. If you have questions don't hesitate to post them here, I or others will try to help you.

Comment: I seem to have found a better solution for this, do you know how could I get the text from 2 buttons using onItemClick from a GridView? @Luksprog

Comment: If you want to get the text from buttons that are in the GridView item that was just clicked than you can look for them in the view that is passed in to the onItemClick() callback.

Comment: @Luksprog - the way I'm getting a button text now is:
Button b = (Button)view;
String buttonText = b.getText().toString();

Problem is not sure how to get the text of the second button click in the same event

Comment: I'm assuming that you're doing that in the OnClickListener for that button. To get the String of another button which is in another GridView item simply use gridVide.getChildAt(position) assuming that all of the GridView elements are visible.